# How parse a type String to Long in Criteria with JPA using expression LIKE?

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm new here, I have a problem writting a method where I tried to call a expression with criteria using JPA and Spring, I have the next code:

```
@Override
    public List<ContractOrder> getOrdersByIn(List<String> paramsIn ) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ContractOrder> query = builder.createQuery(ContractOrder.class);

        Root<ContractOrder> root = query.from(ContractOrder.class);

        Expression<String> exp = root.get("**order_id**");
        Predicate predicateIn = exp.**in**(paramsIn);

        ParameterExpression<Long> pexp = builder.parameter(Long.class,"order_id");
        Predicate predicateLike = builder.like(exp, pexp);

        query.where(builder.or(predicateIn,predicateLike));

        TypedQuery<ContractOrder> queryT = entityManager.createQuery(query.select(root));

        queryT.setParameter(0, Long.valueOf("%5"));

        List<ContractOrder> lista  = queryT.getResultList();

        return lista;
    }
```

Where "order_id" is mapping as type long and I want to pass a parameter like this **"%5"**.

Can you help me with it?

Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

Why this `%5` ???
It's a variable ???????

```
queryT.setParameter(0, Long.valueOf(5));
```

or

```
queryT.setParameter(0, Long.valueOf("5"));
```

should be OK.

Why `**` and not just `*` ?I don't understand...

```
   Predicate predicateIn = exp.**in**(paramsIn);
```

Is it compile?????

Comment: Editor puts ** in that line. This is the correct:  *Predicate predicateIn = exp.in(paramsIn)* ... I still learning JPA Criteria and I don't know how the API can knows where is the '%'. I want to convert this query to criteria... *WHERE order_id like '%5'*, but in the table "order_id" is a type number and my Entity is a type long :(

Comment: what is your DB ? And your Number type has a precision in your DB ?